# Unexpected outcome while reading JSON in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

**Summary:**
I'm trying to write a simple py script that will traverse all the json files in a folder for each image, find the json which has the PhotoImgID the same as the image name and rename the image to match the 'Name' field in the JSON\

Code:

```py
with open(json_path, 'r') as file:
                    try:
                        json_data = json.load(file)

                        # Check if the JSON data contains the required fields
                        if all(field in json_data for field in ['Name', 'PhotoImgID']):
                            photo_img_id = json_data['PhotoImgID']

                            # Check if the photo ID matches the JSON's PhotoImgID
                            if photo_id == photo_img_id:
                                new_filename = json_data['Name'] + os.path.splitext(photo_path)[1]  # Generate new filename
                                new_photo_path = os.path.join(photo_folder, new_filename)

                                # Rename the photo
                                shutil.move(photo_path, new_photo_path)
                                match_found = True
                                break  # Stop searching JSON files once a match is found

                    except (json.JSONDecodeError, KeyError) as e:
                        print(f'Error processing {json_path}: {e}')

            if not match_found:
                not_found_photos.append(filename)`
```

**What error am I getting?**

[It fails for every photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay9hY.png)

Any help is so much appreciated!

**Nushell:**
I'm trying to write a simple py script that takes a photo, reads its name, finds the json file with the corresponding name and rename the photo to match the 'Name' field in JSON.

**Sample JSON:**
`{ "Name": "Adhithya  G", "SecName": "A", "DeptCode": "CSE", "Sex": "F", "PhotoImgID": "6368f927d6c5dfea4ca57c62" }`

Comment: what do you mean "the corresponding name" ?  please be clear. perhaps provide example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: for example: Image_name = 'cool_image.png'. I want to find the json file which has 'cool_image' in the 'PhotoImgID' field. Each JSON file has 4 fields: Name,SecName,DeptCode,Sex and PhtoImgID. I want to fetch the 'Name' field from that particular JSON file and rename the photo based on that. Hope this is clearer